# How to call an external service concurrently as fast as calling by Jmeter in .netCore

Tags: c#, performance, asp.net-core, parallel-processing, jmeter

I have an external service that I want to call it about 1000 times as fast as I can.
when I send 1000 requests by jmeter, it is done in 6 seconds but when I call it in my Code using typed client and a parallel.for loop to repeat 1000 times, it takes about 35 seconds!
How can I send these requests and Recieve data as fast as jmeter?

Here is my code :

```
Parallel.For(0, 1000, i =>
        {
            var data = _client.PostAsJsonAsync(_siteSetting.NahabClientConfig.TokenEndpoint, personInquiryNidRequest).Result;
            var result = data.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<OuterApiResult>().Result;

        });
```

Comment: Could you try adding this line at the start of the program, and see if it makes any difference? `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(1000, 1000);` This is not suggested as a fix, but as a way to troubleshoot the issue that you are observing.

Comment: I tried but it did not change @TheodorZoulias

Comment: The `_client` is an `HttpClient`?

Comment: yes @TheodorZoulias

Answer (score 1):

Just try that:

```
var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000).Select(async i => {
   var data = await _client.PostAsJsonAsync(_siteSetting.NahabClientConfig.TokenEndpoint, personInquiryNidRequest);
   var result = await data.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<OuterApiResult>();
});
await Task.WhenAll(tasks)
```

Task.WhenAll run requests concurrently. Task.Result block thread until end of request and your can't effictive use CPU IO.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I dont know why but it makes execution time longer